# Is buying merchandise or Ubuntu One storage a viable alternative to donating?

Tags: canonical

Canonical offers merchandise and cloud storage (Ubuntu One). Of course, just donating will make Canonical more money then buying merchandise/cloud storage, but is buying merchandise and cloud storage still a viable alternative to donating?

Comment: Yes - something is better than nothing. The income margins on products/services are much lower, but better than nothing at all.

Comment: I would agree with douggro, to put it more plainly, buying storage or merchandise will support Ubuntu, but most of the money paid will cover overhead. On a dollar for dollar basis, more of your money will go toward support by donations but by all means, any support is great.  I purchased "The Clockwork Man" from the Software Center rather that anywhere else b/c it would help support Ubuntu and I always look to the Ubuntu Music store first when purchasing music....